# Combinatorics and Integer solution Based problem

Tags: combinatorics

The number of ways in which we can choose $2$ distinct integers from $1$ to $100$ such that difference between them is at most $10$ is?
(I got the answer as 90+91+92+...+99 by analytical method)
can someone provide me a combinatorial method?

Comment: Your book is right and I believe this question is going to be closed. On MSE, it is best to describe your efforts in solving a proposed problem.

Comment: Hint: In how many ways can you choose two numbers with a difference of exactly 10? Of exactly 9? Of exactly 8? ... Than you can just add those up.

Comment: @RolfSievers This way we get $90+91+92+...+99$ . Is this correct ?

Comment: @SrinivasK how did you get that series?I got 90 for difference of 10,91 for 9 and so on but thats a tedious method!!!!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio So I've been staring at this for a while now, and I continue to fail at finding a purely combinatorial argument for the $\binom{90}{2}$ part. Did you happen to have one in mind when you said the book was right?

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt: $$\sum_{j=1}^{n}j=\binom{n+1}{2},$$ hence: $$\sum_{j=a}^{b}j=\binom{b+1}{2}-\binom{a}{2}.$$

Comment: Ok i got close. Number of ways to choose any to random integer from 1 to 100 is 100C2. Now we got to subtract the cases in which difference between the two random integers exceeds 10. MY APPROACH: FOR ANY RANDOM INTEGER N FROM 1 TO 100 THERE ARE EXACTLY (90-N) INTEGERS FOR WHICH THE DIFFERENCE IS GREATER THAN 10. NOW WE ALSO GOT TO EXCLUDE THE INTEGERS SMALLER THAN N.THAT IS (N-1) INTEGERS. FOR THIS CASE:WE CHOOSE 2 INTEGERS OUT OF (90-N)+(N-1)+(1)=90 INTEGERS. NOW FROM THESE 90 INTEGERS NUMBER OF WAYS TO CHOOSE TWO RANDOM INTEGERS IS 90C2. FINAL ANSWER (100C2-90C2)=945 I GUESS THIS IS FINE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by RolfSievers, 
 
 The number of ways in which we can choose 2 distinct integers from 1 to 100 such that difference between them is exactly: 
  $10 \to  90 ::: {(1,11),(2,12),...,(90,100)}$ 
  $9 \to  91 :::{(1,9),(2,10),...,(91,100)}$ 
  $8 \to  92 $ 
  $7 \to  93 $ 
  $6 \to  94 $ 
  $5 \to  95 $ 
  $4 \to  96 $ 
  $3 \to  97 $ 
  $2 \to  98 $ 
  $1 \to  99 $ 
  So, in the end we get a total of $945$.

Comment: Well this is completely analytical right?

Comment: Or do you have a combinatorial logic in mind.Please let me know?

Comment: @SanchayanDutta I'm not able to spot any combinatorial way to get there. If I get it I'll update my answer for sure. I feel Jack's argument is really amazing and you can use it for now.

Answer (score 5):

Here’s a much shorter and somewhat more combinatorial approach.

For each integer $n\in[1,90]$ there are $10$ pairs having $n$ as smaller member; that’s $900$ pairs. In addition, each of the $\binom{10}9=45$ pairs of integers in $\{91,\ldots,100\}$ must be counted, for a total of $945$ pairs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution written down anew, with less numbers and more combinatorics. This is most likely not the solution intended by the book, but it
just as valid.

We ask about the number of ways one can select two distinct numbers out of $1,\dots, n$ such that their distance is at most $a$.

---

To break this problem down into pieces, consider the number of ways to select two distinct numbers out of $1,\dots,n$ such that their distance is **exacty** $a$.

Assuming the lower number is $x$, the higher number is $x+a$. We are restricted by

- $1 \leq x$ as well as
- $x+a \leq n ⇔ x \leq n - a$.

As a consequence we collect $n-a$ tuples of the form $(1,a+1), \dots, (n-a, n)$.

---

We can understand the condition “the distance is at most a” as “the distance is in $\{1,\dots,a\}$” and sum accordingly.
$$\sum_{d=1}^{a} (n-d) = \sum_{d=1}^{a} n - \sum_{d=1}^{a} d = an - \frac{a(a-1)}{2}$$

Plugging in $n=100, a=10$ yields $1000 - 55 = 945$.